# How can I make an Adapter ListView on a Fragment using an SQL database?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-listview, android-database

I'm trying to call or see a ListView with this kind of specification:

[Wireframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04aAj.png)

Here is my code. This is the fragment named EducacionFragment, and here is where I want to call the layout "eventos":

```
public class EducacionFragment extends ListFragment{
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.eventos_layout, container, false);

        //((MainActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Eventos");
        //Elementos_Eventos elementos_eventos = new Elementos_Eventos();

        ListView listview =(ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listView2);

        Adaptador_Eventos adaptador = new Adaptador_Eventos(getActivity());

        //adaptador = new Adaptador_Eventos(getActivity());

        listview.setAdapter(adaptador);

        return view;
    }
}'
```

Here is my class named Elementos_Eventos, where I get all the information from my database, and put in a list:

```
public class Elementos_Eventos {

    //URL to get JSON Array
    private static String url = "http://ucwm.co.nf/Evento_app.php";

    //JSON Node Names
    private static final String TAG_EVENTOS = "eventos";
    private static final String TAG_ID = "idEvento";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "Nombre";
    private static final String TAG_DESCRIP = "Descripcion";
    private static final String TAG_FECHAI = "FechaInicio";
    private static final String TAG_HORA = "Hora";
    private static final String TAG_FECHAF = "FechaFinal";
    private static final String TAG_LUGAR = "Lugar";
    private static JSONArray eventos = null;

    public static List<Elemento_Eventos> listaElementos = elementos();

    public Elementos_Eventos() {
        listaElementos = elementos();
    }

    static Elemento_Eventos elemento(int id) {
        return listaElementos.get(id);
    }

    public static ArrayList<Elemento_Eventos> elementos() {

        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject json;

        // Getting JSON from URL
        json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

        ArrayList<Elemento_Eventos> elementos;
        elementos = null;
        try {
            // Getting JSON Array from URL
            eventos = json.getJSONArray(TAG_EVENTOS);

            elementos = new ArrayList<Elemento_Eventos>();

            for (int i = 0; i < eventos.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject c = eventos.getJSONObject(i);

                // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
                String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                String nombre = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                String descripcion = c.getString(TAG_DESCRIP);
                String fechaInicio = c.getString(TAG_FECHAI);
                String hora = c.getString(TAG_HORA);
                String fechaFinal = c.getString(TAG_FECHAF);
                String lugar = c.getString(TAG_LUGAR);

                elementos.add(new Elemento_Eventos(id, nombre,descripcion, fechaInicio, hora, fechaFinal, lugar));
            }

        }
        catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return elementos;
    }

    public List<String> listaElementos()
    {
        ArrayList<String> todos = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (Elemento_Eventos e:listaElementos)
            todos.add(e.getNombre());
        return todos;
    }

    public static int size() {
        return listaElementos.size();
    }
```

Here is my class named Elemento_Eventos, where I declare a element one by one:

```
public class Elemento_Eventos {
    private String id;
    private String nombre;
    private String descripcion;
    private String feInicio;
    private String hora;
    private String feFinal;
    private String lugar;

    public Elemento_Eventos(String id,String nombre, String descripcion, String feInicio, String hora, String feFinal, String lugar){
        setId(id);
        setNombre(nombre);
        setDescripcion(descripcion);
        setFeInicio(feInicio);
        setHora(hora);
        setFeFinal(feFinal);
        setLugar(lugar);
    }

    //*********INICIO DE LOS SETS******************
    public void setId(String id){
        this.id=id;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre){
        this.nombre=nombre;
    }

    public void setDescripcion(String descripcion){
        this.descripcion=descripcion;
    }

    public void setFeInicio(String feInicio){
        this.feInicio=feInicio;
    }

    public void setHora(String hora){
        this.hora=hora;
    }

    public void setFeFinal(String feFinal){
        this.feFinal=feFinal;
    }

    public void setLugar(String lugar){
        this.lugar=lugar;
    }

    //*********FINAL DE LOS SETS******************

    //*********INICIO DE LOS GETS******************
    public String getId(){
        return id;
    }

    public String getNombre(){
        return nombre;
    }

    public String getDescripcion(){
        return descripcion;
    }

    public String getFeInicio(){
        return feInicio;
    }

    public String getHora(){
        return hora;
    }

    public String getFeFinal(){
        return feFinal;
    }

    public String getLugar(){
        return lugar;
    }
    //*********FINAL DE LOS SETS******************
 }
```

And finally here is my class named Adaptador_Eventos, where I put all this information in textViews:

```
public class Adaptador_Eventos extends BaseAdapter{

    private final Activity actividad;

    public Adaptador_Eventos(Activity actividad) {
        super();
        this.actividad = actividad;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Elemento_Eventos elemento = Elementos_Eventos.elemento(position);

        LayoutInflater inflater = actividad.getLayoutInflater();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.elemento_eventos, null,true);
        TextView nombreDelEvento, lugar, fecha, descripcion;
        ImageView logo_tipo;
        nombreDelEvento = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nom_evento);
        lugar = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lugar_evento);
        fecha = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.fecha_evento);
        descripcion = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.desc_evento);
        logo_tipo = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        nombreDelEvento.setText(elemento.getNombre());
        lugar.setText(elemento.getLugar());
        fecha.setText(elemento.getFeInicio());
        descripcion.setText(elemento.getDescripcion());

        int id = R.drawable.kcc;
        logo_tipo.setImageResource(id);
        logo_tipo.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_END);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return Elementos_Eventos.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return Elementos_Eventos.elemento(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
}
```

And when I call the fragment Educacion, it crashes my aplication with the message

> Unfortunately, Unidas Contigo A.C. has stopped

Here's the stack trace that appears:

```html
11-12 05:10:00.279    7414-7414/? D/dalvikvm? Late-enabling CheckJNI
11-12 05:10:01.059    7414-7414/com.example.juanisaac.unidascontigoac W/dalvikvm? VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)
11-12 05:10:01.095    7414-7414/com.example.juanisaac.unidascontigoac I/dalvikvm? Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onSearchRequested, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onSearchRequested
11-12 05:10:01.107    7414-7414/com.example.juanisaac.unidascontigoac W/dalvikvm? VFY: unable to resolve interface method 15449: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z
11-12 05:10:01.119    7414-7414/com.example.juanisaac.unidascontigoac D/dalvikvm? VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
11-12 05:10:01.123    7414-7414/com.example.juanisaac.unidascontigoac I/dalvikvm? Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode
11-12 05:10:01.139    7414-7414/com.example.juanisaac.unidascontigoac W/dalvikvm? VFY: unable to resolve interface method 15453: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
11-12 05:10:01.139    7414-7414/com.example.juanisaac.unidascontigoac D/dalvikvm? VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
11-12 05:10:01.407    7414-7414/com.example.juanisaac.unidascontigoac I/AppCompatViewInflater? app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.
11-12 05:10:01.419    7414-7414/com.example.juanisaac.unidascontigoac I/dalvikvm? Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
11-12 05:10:01.423    7414-7414/com.example.juanisaac.unidascontigoac W/dalvikvm? VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 426: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
11-12 05:10:01.423    7414-7414/com.example.juanisaac.unidascontigoac D/dalvikvm? VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
11-12 05:10:01.431    7414-7414/com.example.juanisaac.unidascontigoac I/dalvikvm? Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
11-12 05:10:01.439    7414-7414/com.example.juanisaac.unidascontigoac W/dalvikvm? VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 448: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
11-12 05:10:01.439    7414-7414/com.example.juanisaac.unidascontigoac D/dalvikvm? VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
11-12 05:10:01.479    7414-7414/com.example.juanisaac.unidascontigoac I/AppCompatViewInflater? app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.
11-12 05:10:01.547    7414-7416/com.example.juanisaac.unidascontigoac D/dalvikvm? GC_CONCURRENT freed 192K, 3% free 8841K/9068K, paused 13ms+0ms, total 26ms
11-12 05:10:01.631    7414-7414/com.example.juanisaac.unidascontigoac D/dalvikvm? GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5K, 3% free 8858K/9068K, paused 13ms, total 14ms
11-12 05:10:01.707    7414-7414/com.example.juanisaac.unidascontigoac I/dalvikvm-heap? Grow heap (frag case) to 10.120MB for 1517220-byte allocation
11-12 05:10:01.719    7414-7424/com.example.juanisaac.unidascontigoac D/dalvikvm? GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 3% free 10340K/10552K, paused 14ms, total 14ms
11-12 05:10:01.739    7414-7416/com.example.juanisaac.unidascontigoac D/dalvikvm? GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 3% free 10340K/10552K, paused 8ms+0ms, total 11ms
11-12 05:10:01.759    7414-7414/com.example.juanisaac.unidascontigoac D/dalvikvm? GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 3% free 10339K/10552K, paused 6ms, total 6ms
11-12 05:10:01.875    7414-7414/com.example.juanisaac.unidascontigoac I/dalvikvm-heap? Grow heap (frag case) to 15.908MB for 6068844-byte allocation
11-12 05:10:01.887    7414-7424/com.example.juanisaac.unidascontigoac D/dalvikvm? GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 2% free 16266K/16480K, paused 12ms, total 12ms
11-12 05:10:01.919    7414-7416/com.example.juanisaac.unidascontigoac D/dalvikvm? GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 2% free 16266K/16480K, paused 7ms+0ms, total 20ms
11-12 05:10:02.051    7414-7414/com.example.juanisaac.unidascontigoac D/libEGL? loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_genymotion.so
11-12 05:10:02.067    7414-7414/com.example.juanisaac.unidascontigoac D/? HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb92c56a8, tid 7414
11-12 05:10:02.087    7414-7414/com.example.juanisaac.unidascontigoac D/libEGL? loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_genymotion.so
11-12 05:10:02.087    7414-7414/com.example.juanisaac.unidascontigoac D/libEGL? loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_genymotion.so
11-12 05:10:02.147    7414-7414/com.example.juanisaac.unidascontigoac W/EGL_genymotion? eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
11-12 05:10:02.171    7414-7414/com.example.juanisaac.unidascontigoac D/OpenGLRenderer? Enabling debug mode 0
11-12 05:10:04.511    7414-7414/com.example.juanisaac.unidascontigoac I/Choreographer? Skipped 46 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-12 05:10:05.599    7414-7414/com.example.juanisaac.unidascontigoac W/dalvikvm? Exception Landroid/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException; thrown while initializing Lcom/example/juanisaac/unidascontigoac/Elementos_Eventos;
11-12 05:10:05.599    7414-7414/com.example.juanisaac.unidascontigoac D/AndroidRuntime? Shutting down VM
11-12 05:10:05.603    7414-7414/com.example.juanisaac.unidascontigoac W/dalvikvm? threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa620e908)
11-12 05:10:05.615    7414-7414/com.example.juanisaac.unidascontigoac E/AndroidRuntime? FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
            at com.example.juanisaac.unidascontigoac.Adaptador_Eventos.getCount(Adaptador_Eventos.java:57)
            at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:462)
            at com.example.juanisaac.unidascontigoac.Fragments.EducacionFragment.onCreateView(EducacionFragment.java:40)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1016)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1197)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1562)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:483)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
            at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
            at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
            at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
            at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
            at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
            at com.example.juanisaac.unidascontigoac.JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl(JSONParser.java:37)
            at com.example.juanisaac.unidascontigoac.Elementos_Eventos.elementos(Elementos_Eventos.java:55)
            at com.example.juanisaac.unidascontigoac.Elementos_Eventos.<clinit>(Elementos_Eventos.java:39)
            at com.example.juanisaac.unidascontigoac.Adaptador_Eventos.getCount(Adaptador_Eventos.java:57)
            at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:462)
            at com.example.juanisaac.unidascontigoac.Fragments.EducacionFragment.onCreateView(EducacionFragment.java:40)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1016)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1197)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1562)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:483)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-12 05:10:08.059    7414-7414/com.example.juanisaac.unidascontigoac I/Process? Sending signal. PID: 7414 SIG: 9
```

Comment: You need to provide us the full error message with the stack trace that you get. Otherwise we cannot do much to help you.

Comment: there may be some problem with the list count in your adapter. But need full logcat

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with the above code. When a class is loaded the first time, it is getting data from a URL in elementos() function which is happening by call to setAdapter in onCreate().

Network activity on the main/UI thread is not allowed on Android. Hence, it is throwing NetworkOnMainThread as an exception.

Second, you should connect to the URL using asyncTask and create listaElements list in onPostExecute() preferrably.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a list variable and use it to return the object in your getCount() function;

```
List<Elemento_Eventos> myList = new ArrayList<Elemento_Eventos>();

public Adaptador_Eventos(Activity actividad,  List<Elemento_Eventos> myList){
    super();
    this.actividad = actividad;
    this.myList = myList;
}
```

Then in your getCount function:

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return myList.size();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For class Adaptador_Eventos, change

```
public static List<Elemento_Eventos> listaElementos = elementos();

public Elementos_Eventos() {
    listaElementos = elementos();
}
```

to

```
public static List<Elemento_Eventos> listaElementos ;

public Elementos_Eventos() {
}

public static void init(){
    listaElementos = elementos();
}
```

For class EducacionFragment, change

```
public class EducacionFragment extends ListFragment{
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.eventos_layout, container, false);

        //((MainActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Eventos");
        //Elementos_Eventos elementos_eventos = new Elementos_Eventos();

        ListView listview =(ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listView2);

        Adaptador_Eventos adaptador = new Adaptador_Eventos(getActivity());

        //adaptador = new Adaptador_Eventos(getActivity());

        listview.setAdapter(adaptador);

        return view;
    }
}
```

to

```
public class EducacionFragment extends ListFragment{
    private ListView listview;
    private Adaptador_Eventos adaptador;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.eventos_layout, container, false);

        //((MainActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Eventos");
        //Elementos_Eventos elementos_eventos = new Elementos_Eventos();

        listview =(ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listView2);

        adaptador = new Adaptador_Eventos(getActivity());

        //adaptador = new Adaptador_Eventos(getActivity());

        new AsyncTask(){
            @Override
            protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {
                Elementos_Eventos.init();
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
                super.onPostExecute(o);
                listview.setAdapter(adaptador);
            }
        }.execute();

        return view;
    }
}
```

Try it, and use AsyncTask to avoid a NetworkOnMainThread exception.